# How to check which fonts are used by a Windows program?

Tags: windows, fonts

A program I'm running on my Windows 10 x64 seem to be missing a font (shows me "???" instead of text), is there a way to check which font it is trying to use? I've tried some dependency checkers by they only show system DLL files, not fonts.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with the name of the application or a screenshot?

Comment: I doubt it would help--it's a small configuration tool for a device, even the distributor cannot tell which font is used in it. Here is the link to it though: http://www.owen.ru/uploads/txtlic.php?url=/uploads/m110_v11060.zip

Comment: What language is your system set to?

Comment: English, but I tried with the language the program was written in, no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to find out what files the process is looking for while it is running. If you filter for typical font file name extensions such as .fon, .otf, and .ttf, you'll quickly see what fonts the process is attempting to use.

Comment: I haven't yet found the font, but it's a nice tool to have indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on how this application works? Maybe include some screenshots of it capturing the font used?